# Order of receiving messages if Kafka consumer subscribes to multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer that polls multiple topics. For this question, I've limited one partition per topic. Let's say by the time the consumer started polling, each topic has some data.
What is the order of reads?

Is it round-robin? Is it read all from first before the next? I use `consumer.poll(N)` to poll.

Comment: It's linear within a given topic-partition, but I think each poll loop will round robin to other topics... Certainly you could easily test this by printing the record metadata?

Comment: Yes, for the first. About the second - yes, I could do that, but that could be circumstantial. Does the Kafka spec say that anywhere (couldn't find it)?

Comment: I'm not able to find anything like that, no. https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: will be hard to find anything about it without just testing on some bigger amount of messages. Common sense may say its kind of round robin / random as otherwise hiper active topic would take consumer for itself and it would never read message from other topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ordering is rather complicated. Here is how it works for Kafka 2.6:

- when you assign topic partitions to a consumer, those will be kept in a hash table, therefore the order will be stable, but not necessarily the one you used
- when you call `Consumer.poll(N)` it returns all the enqueued messages, but at most `max.poll.records` (see below)
- when nothing is enqueued, all the topic partitions you assigned, are partitioned per Kafka node, where the leader of that topic-partition resides
- each of those lists is sent to each respective nodes in a fetch request
- each node will return at most `fetch.max.bytes` (or at least one message if available)
- the node will fill those bytes with messages from the requested partitions, always starting with the first
- if there are no more messages in the current partition left, but there are still bytes to fill, it will move to the next partition, until there are no more messages or the buffer is full
- the node can also decide to stop using the current partition and continue with the next one, even if there are still messages available in the current one
- after the client/consumer receives the buffer, it will split it into `CompletedFetches`, where one `CompletedFetch` contains exactly all the messages of one topic partition from the buffer
- those `CompletedFetches` are enqueued (they may contain 0 message or 1000 or more). There will be one `CompletedFetch` for every requested topic partition
- since all the requests to the nodes are run in parallel, but there is only one queue, the `CompletedFetches`/topic partitions may be mixed up in the final result as opposed to the original assignment order
- the enqueued `CompletedFetches` are logically flattened into one big queue
- `Consumer.poll(N)` will read and dequeue at most `max.poll.records` from that flattened big queue
- before the records are returned to the caller of `poll`, another fetch request to all nodes is started, but this time, all the topic partitions that are already in the flattened queue are excluded
- this holds for all future `poll` calls

In practice that means that you'll have no starving, but you may have a large number of messages from one topic, before you'll get a large number of messages for the next topic.

In tests with a message size of 10 bytes, there were around 58000 messages read from one topic, before roughly the same amount was read from the next.
All topics were prefilled with 1 million messages.

Therefore you'll have a kind of batched round robin.

Answer (score 3):

There is no ordering, as the underlying protocol allows sending requests for multiple partitions in one request.

When you invoke `consumer.poll(N)` the client really sends `FetchRequest` objects to brokers that are hosting partition leaders (see `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.createFetchRequests()`) - and it's only one request per node, not per partition.

What is important is that the client can send one FetchRequest for *multiple* partitions (see [protocol spec](http://kafka.apache.org/0110/protocol.html#The_Messages_Fetch)).