# Kafka consumer with multiple topics - strategy

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm currently thinking about if it makes sense to have a Kafka consumer consuming from 20 different topics, all with a differnet number of partitions. All topics have also different message arrival rates, some fast, some slow.

My consumer does data processing and publishes again in different output topics.
I know that Kafka neither guarantees message order across partitions, nor across topics.

How is in general the strategy to consume across topics? Probably not round robin and probably also not read all from 1 topic, then next?
Are topics with slow message arrival rates guaranteed to be processed after some time?
I would expect more consumption from topics with fast message rate, and from time to time consuming the slow ones.

I only found another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149012/order-of-receiving-messages-if-kafka-consumer-subscribes-to-multiple-topics) as a reference. This sounds like I would be reading a huge number of messages from 1 topic, before reading from the next.

Comment: You can have one consumer group, but multiple threads assigned to different topics. That would scale better than one thread and 20 topics

Comment: You can read this article. It covers your question to some extent. https://medium.com/@maverick11/kafka-consume-messages-from-multiple-queues-bdf0e07329b1#:~:text=Yes%2C%20Kafka's%20design%20allows%20consumers,as%20well)%20in%20one%20request

Comment: "The author deleted this Medium story."